Question about Batchim - when does a consonant be pronounced as a double consonant?
I learnt that when ㄱ,ㄷ,ㅂ,ㅅ,ㅈ, ㅋ,ㅌ,ㅍ,ㅊ are the 받침, the following consonant becomes a double consonant (if possible).
E.g 받다 –> 받따
Does this apply with ㄹ, ㄴ, ㅁ, ㅇ as well?
E.g I hear people saying 할게 as 할께, but I asked someone and they said ㄹ does not pressurise the next consonant so I’m a bit confused.

The first case you mentioned (ㄱ,ㄷ,ㅂ,ㅅ,ㅈ after ㄱ,ㄷ,ㅂ,ㅅ,ㅈ,ㅋ,ㅌ,ㅍ,ㅊ 받침 becoming 된소리 (tensed sound)) applies unconditionally, with no exception.
ㄹ, ㄴ, and ㅁ can also cause tensification of the subsequent consonant, but only under certain conditions. ㅇ does not as far as I know.
Here are cases where ㄹ, ㄴ, and ㅁ 받침 can affect subsequent consonant.

if ㄹ is at the end of a noun-modifying verb or adjective form, the next syllable's initial ㄱ,ㅂ,ㅅ,or ㅈ changes to tensed sound.  This includes some single word forms that have evolved this way as well.

examples: 먹을 것 (머글껃), 할 수 없다 (할쑤업따), 알 바 아니다 (알빠아니다), 모를지라도 (모를찌라도).


ㄴ and ㅁ at the end of a verb or adjective stem makes the next ㄱ,ㅂ,ㅈ,ㅅ tensified.

examples: 안고 (안다 + -고 -> 안꼬), 감지만 (감다 + -지만 -> 감찌만), 품다 (품따).


exceptions: when the next syllable is a causative suffix 기, this doesn't apply, as in 안기다 (안기다), 감기다 (감기다).



할게 follows the #1 principle above.  Although it is an indivisible verb ending, it probably evolved from 할 거이 or something similar. So the language standardization body made 할게 the standard spelling even though it is pronounced as 할께.
The two rules above mostly concern native verbs and adjectives.  Within hanja words, there is a different set of rules.

Read Korean phonology: Consonant assimilation, which has big table showing phonetic realizations of consonant clusters.
